# How to access external storage(sdcard/usb) in an android device in a qt qml based application?

Tags: android, qt, qml, android-permissions, android-sdcard

I am creating a video player application targeting android 13(API 33). I am using Qt Creator 9.0.1 and qt version is 6.4.0. With the Video component in qml, playing videos from internal storage is working. But I need to play videos from usb, how to do that?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

I have added the above mentioned permissions in android manifest file. I am also requesting runtime permissions if the permission is not granted.

```
auto r = QtAndroidPrivate::checkPermission(QtAndroidPrivate::Storage).result();

    QtAndroidPrivate::checkPermission(QtAndroidPrivate::Storage).result();
    if (r == QtAndroidPrivate::Denied)
    {
        qDebug()<<"denied";
        r = QtAndroidPrivate::requestPermission(QtAndroidPrivate::Storage).result();
        if (r == QtAndroidPrivate::Denied)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
```

Still not able to play videos from usb, What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Android 13, you don't really need to request those permissions, users need to request permission using the file dialog and for Qt that's under `QFileDialog`, so to get access to some video file under the external storage, use https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qfiledialog.html#getOpenFileName which gets you a file url and you'll able to open and read its content.